# How to deal with noisy and arrogant co-worker with the attitude?

Tags: company-culture, unprofessional-behavior, noise

There are lot of question related to noisy co-worker but this one (in my opinion) differ in the fact that the co-worker I'm dealing with is displaying an attitude.

I told him that he is loud and asked to do his best to keep the volume low as best as possible upon which he responded that I should practice what I preach. True, I'm dealing with this issue myself but after was told that I'm loud I've purchased noise canceling headphones and doing my best to keep the volume low. For what is worth I think I'm doing a good job.

Often time he would play with his fingers against the table creating noise as if that's something normal.

Also, when I'm at internet meetings people can't hear me and complained about office's background noise.

Today this guy again talking to others as if he is alone in the office after which I stood up and call his name which he ignored. I've asked him this time louder to consider the fact that he is not alone in the office. 
He completely ignored me....

I consider this attitude issue and thinking about raising an issue with my manager and/or HR.

Any wise words before I spring into action ...?

EDIT...

---

I've decided to give another shoot by talking privately with the guy and express my problem with the noise level and inability to concentrate as well as resulting difficulties in communication with the client.

Told him that I'm not keen in escalating this and would like to resolve it internally.

I've said, I'd like to hear from you that you'll do your best to address expressed issues upon which he responded 'Whatever...'

I've asked him to clarify and he said 'OK, I'll do my best'
I hope that's the end of this.

Comment: How is everyone else in your team dealing with this?

Comment: yes, internal conversations, nobody stepping out ...

Comment: FWIW, shouting people's name across the office might also be considered rude. You might want to walk over and talk privately, next time.

Comment: @Erik true, except for the fact that he sits across me (less than 2 meters) and deliberately ignored me. The person he was talking to stopped, but he didn't.
Some people simply don't have regards for others and the context in which concentration is essential for the productivity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time to take it up the chain. Talk to your boss about it, In particular mention that people on the other end of meetings have complained. That is simply unprofessionally unacceptable. Let him deal with it.

BTW playing with your fingers against the table is not abnormal behavior, it is fairly common.

Comment: In lack to properly describe the 'finger play', it has a rhythm that usually ends with fist punch against the table which is if nothing else disruptive

Comment: @krul Talk to your team lead/manager.  Let your manager resolve the situation.

Comment: did mentioned it, but didn't specified the guy attitude... 
looks like he's preoccupied with other more important issues

Comment: You need to specifically explain that people on the other end of phone calls are being affected. This is a critical issue, he must address.